# Iframe error : because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: html, iframe

```html
<iframe src="https://www.mankatomn.gov/city-services-a-z/bus-routes" name="webView" width="100%" height="480"></iframe>
```

**Hi tried to link a web page using I frame like above. But this gives me an error**

[image]

What does this error means? Is this means that I can't embed this web site becasue this site is block to embeding?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means that you can't embedded this page on a third-party site.

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate
>   whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a
>   `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>`. Sites can use this to avoid
>   clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded
>   into other sites.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options